# Reading and Editing .config from another project

Tags: c#, config

During the installation of my application, I need to edit some sections of the Web.config of my application and not my installer.
I've tried to use ConfigurationManager but it's only opening the .config from the .exe we give in parameters. But I don't want to create a file "Web.exe" just for that.

Do you have any ideas for that ? (without using Nuget packages for editing xml files)

Comment: Look at the docs for ConfigurationManager. There are ways to open other config files.

Comment: Maybe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's not working, i've tried these two solutions already. Finally I'm parsing the Web.config with XMLDocument.